# Why am I getting "undefined" when I call .options on my select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to follow this tutorial (http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) to get dynamic select boxes working with RoR. No need to worry about the RoR bit, this is a Javascript specific question.

Every time this function runs I get the error that the "options" is undefined. I've tried running the command manually in the console, but regardless, it spits out undefined. I have it typed exactly as I see it in the tutorial, but somehow it's not working for me...

Here's the javascript in question:

```
function clientSelected() {
var client_id = $('#piece_client_id').val();
// THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE 
var options = $('piece_campaign_id').options;
options.length = 0;
campaigns.each(function(campaign) {
    if (campaign[0] == client_id) {
        options[options.length] = new Option(campaign[1], campaign[2]);
    }
});
if (options.length == 1) {
  $('campaign_field').hide();
} else {
  $('campaign_field').show();
}
}
```

Here is the HTML that it's trying to work on:

```
<select id="piece_campaign_id" name="piece[campaign_id]"><option value=""></option> 
<option value="1">Feed The Dogs</option> 
<option value="2">Watch Television</option> 
<option value="3">End The Suffering</option> 
<option value="4">Brian Bilbrey</option> 
<option value="5">SummerHill Homes / Yes on A&amp;B</option>
</select>
```

Thanks a bunch for taking a look! Let me know if there's anything else I can add to make my question more clear.

Comment: Your `.each()` loop won't work either. I don't know what `campaigns` holds, but the `campaign` parameter is going to point to an index number, so `campaign[0]` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: ...it looks like the tutorial you're following doesn't use `jQuery`. I'm guessing maybe `prototypejs`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
var options = $('#piece_campaign_id').get(0).options;
```

or

```
var options = $('#piece_campaign_id')[0].options;
```

As you were using a jQuery object, which doesn't have an `options` property. Also, make sure to include the id selector (`#`).

Comment: `$('#piece_campaign_id')[0].options` does the same thing, slightly shorter.

Comment: Nice! that was the magic sauce. I had already tried the id selector with no luck so I had reverted. But the get(0) did the trick! I'm going to have to read up on that :D Thanks a ton!

Comment: @counterbeing: basically, adding `[0]` (or `get(0)`) onto the end of any jQuery object gives you the "true" DOM element (or the first DOM element, if several were matched). Conversely, wrapping `$(...)` around any DOM element turns it into a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

The following code in is not accurate.

```
 var options = $('piece_campaign_id').options;
```

Should be

```
 var options = $('#piece_campaign_id')[0].options;
```

You will notice two changes.

1. The addition of the `#` in the selector
2. The addition of the `[0]` after the jQuery object.

In jQuery to select an element by an ID you need to append # before the idvalue (which is similar to CSS.  Here is some reference http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

The next issue was you were trying to access a property that does not exist on a jQuery object. `options` is an HTML DOM property.  Because of this you must access the DOM Object from inside the jQuery Object.

```
var options = $('#piece_campaign_id') //Returns jQuery Object

var options = $('#piece_campaign_id')[0] //Returns HTML DOM Object
//The line above will return the same as
var options = document.getElementById('piece_campaign_id')
```

---

**NOTE**

The following Selectors in your code are most likely inaccurate

```
  $('campaign_field').hide();
  ...
  $('campaign_field').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('piece_campaign_id')
```

needs to be

```
$('#piece_campaign_id')
```